# How to modify loss.backward() in Pytorch to account for np.nan's?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, backpropagation

I am training a simple neural network with Pytorch. My inputs are something like

```
[10.2, nan]
[10.0, 5.0]
[nan, 3.2]
```

Where the first index is always double the second index. I can train the neural network by feeding in examples one by one, such as (10.0, 0), (5.0, 1), where the 0 and 1 corresepond to their indices.

However, I wish to train arrays and output entire arrays. So that my neural network will predict [10.2, 5.1] for the first entry, for instance.

My current issue is that the loss is a tensor([nan]). So loss.backward() doesn't work with the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-03be43016aca> in <module>()
     43                 if training:
     44                     scheduler.step()
---> 45                     loss.backward()
     46                     optimizer.step()
     47                     lr_history.extend(scheduler.get_lr())

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    253                 create_graph=create_graph,
    254                 inputs=inputs)
--> 255         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    256 
    257     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    150 
    151 

RuntimeError: Found dtype Double but expected Float
```

Any advice on how to modify the loss.backward() function (or how create my own) so that that it will ignore nan's?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you fix your labels if you know there is that relationship between the two classes? Are the NaNs important?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. What do you suggest? I need to feed the entire array in as input (e.g. [10, nan]).

Comment: Yes, but your labels are implicit? You can just make the nan values their actual value since they have a defined relationship. Then you don't need to amend your code.